# How to reposition the canvas item through Y value whose height varies dynamically

Tags: javascript, canvas, qml

I have a Qml Canvas Item where in, the height of canvas item keeps varying based on the input dynamically. Below is my code

```
Item {
id: barGraph

property int highestRange: 200
property int rangeVal: (RangeModel.rangeValue === "---") ? highestRange : RangeModel.rangeValue
property int totalHeight: 450
property int canvasHeight: (rangeVal * totalHeight) / highestRange

height: 700
width: 500
x: 120
y: 145

Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    height: canvasHeight
    width: 16

    onPaint: {
        var context = getContext("2d");
        var startX = mycanvas.x;
        var startY = mycanvas.y;
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;
        context.strokeStyle = "white";

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(startX, startY);
        context.lineTo(startX,(mycanvas.height - 10));
        context.lineTo(mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
        context.lineTo(mycanvas.width, startY + 10);
        context.lineTo(mycanvas.width / 2, startY);
        context.closePath(); // base drawn automatically
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }
}}
```

The output of this code look like this :

[image: canvas with full height]

The problem with this code is, whenever the height of the canvas changes dynamically it actually resizes from the below position as shown in the image

[image: resized canvas image].

I actually need this to be resized from the Y top position and keeping the below position unmovable which I am unable to achieve through this code.

Any support is much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your requirement is to use the `Canvas` object to build an isometric bar chart application?

I have refactored a `BarGraph.qml` and replaced `Canvas` with `Shape`, `ShapePath`, and `PathLine`.

I removed the unnecessary `Item` parent and made `Shape` the parent and made everything size accordingly.

There is a mistake in your code. You set `startX` and `startY` to be relative to `canvas.x` and `canvas.y`. This is problematic, since if `canvas.x` and `canvas.y` is non-zero your usage of `startX` and `startY` later will only move the components further.

Instead, all coordinates within your shape must tree the top-left corner of your canvas as (0, 0) regardless of where it is.

To make things position on the bottom, it is based on:

```
y: parent.height - height
```

`parent.height` refers to the height of the page and `height` refers to the height of the `BarGraph`. By assigning this value to `y` it will make the `BarGraph` appear anchored to the bottom instead of the top of the page. Additional math is added later to create the isometric look.

To mock some data up, I use an array of numbers which I feed into the Repeater. This will allow me to create multiple instances of `BarGraph` and use the numbers via `modelData`.

As added bonus, I added a fill color to the `BarGraph` and made the fill color gradually change from "blue" to "white".

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }

    Repeater {
        model: [ 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300 ]
        BarGraph {
            x: index * 30 + 100
            y: parent.height - height - 200 + index * 15
            fillColor: Qt.lighter(Qt.color("blue"), 1.0 + (index % 10) / 10.0)
            height: modelData
        }
    }

    BarXYAxis {
    }
}

// BarGraph.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes
Shape {
    id: shape
    width: 20
    height: 250
    property alias strokeColor: shapePath.strokeColor
    property alias strokeWidth: shapePath.strokeWidth
    property alias fillColor: shapePath.fillColor
    ShapePath {
        id: shapePath
        startX: 0; startY: 0
        strokeColor: "white"
        strokeWidth: 1.0
        fillColor: "blue"
        PathLine { x: 0; y: shape.height - 10 }
        PathLine { x: shape.width; y: shape.height }
        PathLine { x: shape.width; y: 10 }
        PathLine { x: shape.width / 2; y: 0 }
        PathLine { x: 0; y: 0 }
    }
}

// BarXYAxis.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes
Item {
    id: axis

    anchors.fill: parent

    Shape {
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: parent.height - 200 > 30
        ShapePath {
            startX: 80; startY: 30
            strokeColor: "white"
            strokeWidth: 1.0
            fillColor: "transparent"
            PathLine { x: 80; y: parent.height - 200 }
        }
    }

    Shape {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ShapePath {
            startX: 80; startY: parent.height - 200
            strokeColor: "white"
            strokeWidth: 1.0
            fillColor: "transparent"
            PathLine { x: 410; y: parent.height - 35 }
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: Math.floor((axis.height - 230) / 20)

        Shape {
            x: 70
            y: axis.height - 222 - index * 20
            ShapePath {
                startX: 0; startY: 0
                strokeColor: "white"
                strokeWidth: 1.0
                fillColor: "transparent"
                PathLine { x: 4; y: 2 }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using anchors:

```
Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    height: canvasHeight
    anchors.bottom: bargraph.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10    //in case you want some space

    ...
}
```

---

btw, `mycanvas.x` and `mycanvas.y` are 0 in your example, so can be omitted